# Compiling PHP Intl extension on Mac Book Pro (El Capitan 10.11.4)

Tags: php, macos, pear, pecl

I am trying to install the PHP Intl extension on my new Mac (El Capitan 10.11.4) using PECL, but there is a linking error during the `make` stage.

Here are the steps I took:

1. Installed PEAR to run on Mac
2. Compiled and installed the ICU library (version 51.2) into `/usr/local/lib`
3. Ran this command: `sudo pecl install intl` and there was an error (see below). I also tried compiling the extension directly from the PHP source code ("ext" folder) and received the same error message.

I am getting the following error:

```
ld: file not found: libicudata.51.dylib for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [intl.la] Error 1
ERROR: 'make' failed
```

It looks like:

1. The file is missing (even though it knows the correct ICU library version to look for). Maybe it truly can't find the file. The `-L` switch and related switches appear to point to the correct path `/usr/local/lib` path.
2. Then, there is also some sort of architecture mismatch. So, I ran `file libicudata.51.dylib` and it appears to be the right architecture.

Here is what `file` retuned:

```
$ file /usr/local/lib/libicudata.51.dylib
/usr/local/lib/libicudata.51.dylib: Mach-O 64-bit dynamically linked shared library x86_64
```

Has anyone run across this before? Or know how to compile PHP's Intl extension on the new Mac Book Pro (El Capitan 10.11.4)? I a hoping for some hints on where to look next, because I am a bit stumped here.

Comment: What happens when you try to compile a C stub program (`int main(){return 0;}`) with `cc -licudata -o test test.c`?

Comment: I tried as you suggested, and the stub `test.c` program compiles without any error messages.

Comment: Do you need to use PECL? You may want to consider using homebrew as it works very efficiently. http://brew.sh/

Comment: Well, good question. I got a new Mac, and after reading about the SIP constraints, I was thinking it might be best to simply install the applications and libraries individually. It might also be good if I want to learn more about the various switches and options, at least for the software I use more frequently. To your point, I could see that being overkill, too; the bad old days for the average user.

Comment: Where would I look to see any notes in how the package in Homebrew was prepared? Someone must have ran into similar types of errors, when preparing packages for Homebrew. So, is there a place to look that up?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this error, what php version are you using.

Comment: See this https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1710. I use brew too and maybe "brew update && brew reinstall php56 && brew reintsasll icu4c" would work

Comment: The Mac Book Pro laptop came installed with php v5.5.31.

Comment: What is your icu4c version?

Comment: The icu4c version I downloaded was 51.2 because of the PECL binary dependency, but now I am reading it again, I think I should be looking at the PHP docs to find out what version to use. I tried 51.2, 52.1, and the latest 57.1, which all seemed to yield the same error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108474/discussion-between-biagio-arobba-and-dendi-suhubdy).

Comment: Isn't intl included with PHP for a long time now? Have you set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH` before running `pecl`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem,here is my environment:

> OS : El Capitan 10.11.4
>   PHP  : php-7.0.5
>   icu  : 55.1

the key point is reinstall ICU using `--enable-rpath`:

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/oss/icu --enable-release --enable-shared --enable-rpath --enable-tools
```

If you want to know why,please run as root

```
otool -L $YOUR_ICU_PREFIX/lib/libicudata.dylib
```

to check if the first library is absolute path.

Comment: I just went with using brew, so I won't be able to check, but thank you for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Maybe you can try just this:

```
brew install php56-intl
```

Answer (score 2):

You might consider looking at these threads (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1701) and (https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-php/issues/1710). I tried to reproduce your error but I failed. The most probable reason would be an icu4c that is not linked.

Try using `brew link --force icu4c`

I tried using php70 and

```
sudo pecl install intl
```

failed. I tried using php56, everything ran smoothly.

Try running `php -v master`, something like this should show up

```
C02QH2D7G8WM:workspace userone$ php -v master
PHP 5.6.20 (cli) (built: Apr  1 2016 08:53:48) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Comment: I am using php 5.5, it was built Feb 20, 2016

Comment: I can try building php 5.6, and see if building that extension works.

Comment: @BiagioArobba you can brew install php56 and brew unlink php55

Comment: Wait right you compiled it, right go ahead and compile php56

Comment: Ok, I tried upgrading things. So, I compiled the latest ICU 57.1 and PHP 5.6.20, and got the same error message `ld: file not found: ... for architecture x86_64`

Comment: Just a note. I am trying to stay away from using Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

Try run:

```
brew install homebrew/php/php56-intl
```